# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/js/Pages/HomePage.jsx when running php artisan test

Tags: reactjs, laravel, testing

I am trying to write a simple test and I am seeing this error.

I am using Laravel React stack:

- PHP 8.1.1
- Laravel 10.17.1
- React

##### My vite file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

Comment: What is the error? You did not add anything

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to config.vite.js

```
laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.jsx', 'resources/js/Pages/HomePage.jsx'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
```